# como posicionar o Caret de um JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Tenho um `JTextField` onde é opcional a abertura e fechamento de parênteses.
Porém, sempre que o usuário abre e não fecha um parêntese, meu programa dá erro, pois uso esse campo de texto para calcular uma expressão aritmética.

Afim de evitar esse erro, eu gostaria de, assim que o usuário digitasse o `"("` eu completaria com o `")"` e colocaria o caret entre esses caracteres, mas não sei como fazê-lo. Por exemplo:

```
JTextField txt = new JTextField;
txt.setText("2*(");
String ultimoCaractereDigitado = txt.substring (txt.length() - 1, txt.length());

if(ultimoCaractereDigitado.equals("(")){
    txt.setText(ultimoCaractereDigitado+")");
    //text.getText() = 2*()
    txt.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
        @Override
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent caret) {
        //Posição do caret: penúltimo caractere, ou seja, entre o "(" e ")"    
        caret.setDot(txt.getText().length - 2);
        }
    });
}
```

O método `ce.setDot()` não existe, há alguma forma de eu conseguir setar a posição do caret que não seja pelo `caretUpdate` ?

Comment: Por favor, forneça um [mcve] para que seja possivel simular o problema e propor uma solução;

Comment: Acredito que não seja relacionada, pois não quero setar a posição do caret quando o campo de texto ganhar foco, e sim quando eu digitar um determinado caractere ("(" no caso).

Comment: Esse trecho de código não é um [mcve]. Precisa de mais contexto que não foi fornecido.

Comment: Veja se agora está melhor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá pra fazer mesclando o `PlainDocument` e `CaretListener`, onde com a primeira classe você detecta se o que foi digitado no campo é a abertura do parêntese e concatena o fechamento junto, e com a segunda, você posiciona o cursor entre ambos. Para isso, eu utilizei uma variável booleana `hasOpenParentese` para que ambos os métodos tenham uma forma de se "comunicar" e pro `CaretListener` saber quando irá reposicionar o cursor:

```
textField.setDocument(new PlainDocument() {

    @Override
    public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (str == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (str.equals("(")) {
            hasOpenParentese = true;
            str += ")";
        }
        super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
    }
});

textField.addCaretListener(e -> {
    if (hasOpenParentese) {
        hasOpenParentese = false;
        JTextComponent comp = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
        comp.setCaretPosition(e.getDot() - 1);
    }
});
```

Que resulta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um exemplo executável no [**github**](https://github.com/diegofelipem/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/swing/examples3/JTextFieldWithCaretExample.java), caso queira testar antes de aplicar no seu código.