# Dúvidas com máscara em JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, formatação

Trabalhando com `JFormattedTextField`, obtive dois problemas para os quais não encontrei nada que me ajuda-se a resolver. O exemplo nesse caso seria um `JFormattedTextField` para CPF.

Primeiro problema: a máscara. Quando crio a máscara e executo o programa, a formatação já fica automaticamente aparecendo no sistema. Queria que só mostrasse os caracteres especiais durante a digitação dos números ou após ter digitado.

```
try {
        txtCPF.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("###.###.###-##")));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Como pode se ver no código, todos os "." e "-" já aparecem no início, antes de poder alterar qualquer coisa.

Segundo problema: aviso. Quando digito uma informação que é menor que o tamanho da minha máscara (quantidade de "#") e ele apaga as informações inseridas. Mas além disso, queria que aparecesse uma mensagem para o usuário que o valor digitado foi inválido.

Abaixo está um exemplo para teste e análise dos problemas:

```
package telas;

public class amostra extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public amostra() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jFormattedTextField1 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try {
            jFormattedTextField1.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("###.###.###-##")));
        } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        jLabel1.setText("cpf");

        jLabel2.setText("Outro campo:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(69, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                    .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 121, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(126, 126, 126))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(101, 101, 101)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addContainerGap(141, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(amostra.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(amostra.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(amostra.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(amostra.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new amostra().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

Comment: Ou utilizando JTextField + PlainDocument.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada no link para ver se consigo resolver, aviso caso tenha conseguido, obrigado

Comment: Analisando melhor, a outra pergunta não resolve tanto essa. Mas essa caracteristica é da mascara, não tem como evitar, só se você escrever uma máscara manualmente, o que acho bobagem demais se já tem pronto. A segunda duvida, basta validar pelo número de caracteres digitados, se form menor que 14(11 digitos + 3 separadores) é porque não foi preenchido corretamente.

Comment: @Articuno Você continua achando que é duplicata? Na minha opinião é apenas algo parecido que deve ter uma solução próxima, mas ainda assim não seria duplicata, pois as respostas de lá não respondem por completo o problema daqui.

Comment: @VictorStafusa conforme meu ultimo comentário, analisando melhor não parece ser uma duplicata mesmo, apesar de ser possível adaptar a outra resposta para atender a essa, porém isso não qualifica ela como duplicata.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando `JFormattedTextField` acredito ser mais complicado, tendo em vista que teríamos que reescrever uma mascara personalizada, mas gostaria de deixar uma opção alternativa bem mais simples, utilizando `JTextField` e `PlainDocument`, onde é possível não somente filtrar apenas dígitos, mas também adicionar os separadores de CPF em tempo de digitação. Utilizei como base o código [**desta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/133841/28595) e [**desta outra**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/218266/28595), onde você pode encontrar maiores explicações sobre as classes envolvidas.

Para demonstrar, fiz este componente que herda de `JTextField`:

```
class CPFTextField extends JTextField {

    public CPFTextField() {

        setDocument(new PlainDocument() {

            @Override
            public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

                if (str == null || !Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))) {
                    return;
                }

                if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= 14) {

                    if (offset > 0 && offset < 9 && (offset + 1) % 4 == 0) {
                        str = "." + str;
                    } else if (offset > 0 && (offset + 1) % 12 == 0) {
                        str = "-" + str;
                    }
                    super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Na condição `((getLength() + str.length()) <= 14)` eu verifico se o tamanho da string atual somada ao que acabou de ser digitado vai exceder o tamanho de 14 caracteres, que seria o tamanho máximo do campo, somando os 11 dígitos de CPF e os 3 separadores.

No if mais interno, eu fiz uma validação para adicionar o ponto como separador, tendo em vista que a cada 3 dígitos eu teria que adicionar um ponto, utilizei `(offset+1)%4==0` pois o ponto aparecerá a cada 4 posições. Como temos 14 posições, tive que adicionar `offset < 9` pois o ponto só será adicionado 2 vezes(na quarta e oitava posição).

Seguindo a mesma lógica anterior, adicionei `(offset+1)%12==0` para que o hífen fosse adicionado como separador dos dígitos finais do CPF, que é exatamente a posição 12.

Nosso campo agora formata conforme o usuário digita, mas ainda não o impede de digitar qualquer coisa, e é utilizando o `!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))` que eu permito que seja adicionado apenas dígitos por entrada de usuário e descarto qualquer outra coisa digitada que não seja um dígito.

Para usar, basta instanciar como um componente de texto qualquer:

```
CPFTextField field = new CPFTextField();
```

e adicionar na sua tela, pois continua sendo um `JTextField`, apesar do que personalizamos na classe. Para validar, basta verificar se o o texto do componente é igual a 14, caso não seja, não foi preenchido corretamente.

Fiz um exemplo executável no [**GitHub**](https://github.com/diegofelipem/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/swing/examples4/JTextFieldCPFFormatterTest.java), se quiser ver ele funcionando antes de aplicar no seu código.